# max sum of list elements each separated by (at least) k elements

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

given a list of numbers to find the maximum sum of non-adjacent elements with time complexity o(n) and space complexity of o(1), i could use this :

```
sum1= 0
sum2= list[0]

for i in range(1, len(list)):
    num= sum1
    sum1= sum2+ list[i]
    sum2= max(num, sum2)

print(max(sum2, sum1))
```

this code will work only if the k = 1 [ only one element between the summing numbers] how could improve it by changing k value using dynamic programming. where k is the number of elements between the summing numbers.
for example:

list = [5,6,4,1,2]   k=1
answer = 11 # 5+4+2

list = [5,6,4,1,2] k=2
answer = 8 # 6+2

list = [5,3,4,10,2]   k=1
answer = 15 # 5+10

Comment: When I run your code, I get 13 instead of 11. I don't see how it enforces at least one number is between the numbers being summed.

Comment: Are all numbers non-negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick implementation of the algorithm described by Ami Tavory (as far as I understand it). It should work for any sequence, though if your list is all negative, the maximum sum will be `0` (the sum of an empty subsequence).

```
import collections

def max_sum_separated_by_k(iterable, k):
    best = collections.deque([0]*(k+1), k+1)
    for item in iterable:
        best.appendleft(max(item + best[-1], best[0]))
    return best[0]
```

This uses `O(k)` space and `O(N)` time. All of the `deque` operations, including appending a value to one end (and implicitly removing one from the other end so the length limit is maintained) and reading from the ends, are `O(1)`.

If you want the algorithm to return the maximum subsequence (rather than only its sum), you can change the initialization of the `deque` to start with empty lists rather than `0`, and then append `max([item] + best[-1], best[0], key=sum)` in the body of the loop. That will be quite a bit less efficient though, since it adds `O(N)` operations all over the place.

Comment: How do I display the indexes of the maximum subsequence, as opposed to the values.

Answer (score 5):

It's possible to solve this with space *O(k)* and time *O(nk)*. if *k* is a constant, this fits the requirements in your question.

The algorithm loops from position *k + 1* to *n*. (If the array is shorter than that, it can obviously be solved in *O(k)*). At each step, it maintains an array `best` of length *k + 1*, such that the *j*th entry of `best` is the best solution found so far, such that the last element it used is at least *j* to the left of the current position.

Initializing `best` is done by setting, for its entry *j*, the largest non-negative entry in the array in positions *1, ..., k + 1 - j*. So, for example, `best[1]` is the largest non-negative entry in positions *1, ..., k*, and `best[k + 1]` is 0.

When at position *i* of the array, element *i* is used or not. If it is used, the relevant `best` until now is `best[1]`, so write `u = max(best[1] + a[i], best[1])`. If element *i* is not used, then each "at least" part shifts one, so for *j = 2, ..., k + 1*, `best[j] = max(best[j], best[j - 1])`. Finally, set `best[1] = u`.

At the termination of the algorithm, the solution is the largest item in `best`.

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:
I had misunderstood the question, if you need to have 'atleast' k elements in between then following is an `O(n^2)` solution.

If the numbers are non-negative, then the DP recurrence relation is:

```
DP[i] = max (DP[j] + A[i]) For all j st 0 <= j < i - k 
      = A[i] otherwise.
```

If there are negative numbers in the array as well, then we can use the idea from Kadane's algorithm:

```
DP[i] = max (DP[j] + A[i]) For all j st 0 <= j < i - k && DP[j] + A[i] > 0
      = max(0,A[i]) otherwise.
```

Comment: thanks a lot, your way works correctly but for example if k=1 it will always sum as it one different between them, since in other cases is possible to get higher sum if we leave more then one space between them. sorry maybe my question was't that clear I should write "at least k elements between the summing number". I just edit the question

Answer (score 0):

Not sure for the complexity but coding efficiency landed me with

```
max([sum(l[i::j]) for j in range(k,len(l)) for i in range(len(l))])
```

(I've replace `list` variable by `l` not to step on a keyword).

Comment: This is wrong. It just checks evenly-spaced subsequences for different starting positions and even-spaced jumps. The optimal subsequence does not necessarily have equal-spaced jumps.